# Hide a specifc field in update but not in create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to show the password field only in create form, but not in the update form. If I remove the password from UserSerializer, it won't appear in both forms.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscriptions = SubscriptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Have you considered using different serializers for different forms?

Comment: Should I create another viewset for this or can I use the same one to both serializers?

Comment: @YuriSales no, you only need define a new serializer. Checkout the viewset's `get_serializer_class` method. If you override it, you can dynamically assign a serilaizer class depending on the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove password field if instance is provided to serializer. That means you are going to update it (instance) or serialize it. In both cases you won't need password field.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscriptions = SubscriptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields.pop('password')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()

        return user
```